# Laravel 5.6 migrations

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with migrations in a Laravel 5.6.

This is a problem:

[image]

My code in a Laravel:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
}
```

What i need to do?

Comment: Laravel 6.6 does not exist. Did you mean Laravel 5.6?

Comment: Try with `Schema::hasTable('tableName')`

Comment: I am sorry. I thought 5.6 :D.

Comment: It is complaining that the table already exists. If you are trying to run this migration it may be worth dropping the existing table currently. If you want to run all migrations again (Warning will loose all data) you can run `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: I tried with **php artisan migrate:fresh** . It does not work.

Comment: try php artisan migrate:refresh. it will refresh your complete database

Comment: When i saw in my phpmyadmin, there is all tables with columns, but error stands in terminal.

Comment: Did you create this migration twice by any chance?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your migrations folder

Comment: I solved a problem, thank everyone...

Comment: Can you post your solution as self answer? You could possibly help future askers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the error message "companies" table already exist. 
you can use following commands to resolve it.

php artisan migrate:rollback

php artisan migrate:reset

please refer the laravel documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Table already exists as it is telling you in the message, you may need to drop it first or check that you're using the right database name in your ENV file. Also check you're not creating the table companies in a previous migration.

If you're trying to add fields to an existing table you don't need the *create* method but:

```
Schema::table("companies", function (Blueprint $table) {
        // The fields you need
});
```

Also for the **foreign key** is safer to use unsignedInteger as data type

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to drop every table and migrate before that you have to take a backup of your sql because it deletes every data

```
 php artisan migrate:fresh
```